# Synchronized variable in class which are parent and child class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

there are two class for parameters setting

```
class AParameters
{
public:
    AParameters();
    int test1 = 0;
    int test2 = 0;
};
```

```
class BParameters : public AParameters
{
public:
    BParameters();
    int test3 = 0;
    int test4 = 0;
};
```

and there are two class for test

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    void SetParameters(AParameters);
    BParameters GetParameters();

private:
    AParameters a;
};
```

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B();
    void SetParameters(BParameters);
    BParameters GetParameters();
private:
    BParameters b;
};
```

I want to set A's parameters(a) and can synchronize the value to B's parameters(b).

and set B's parameters(b) can synchronize the value to A's parameters(a).

For example:

```
B *myB = new B;
A *mya = myB;
AParameters aa;
aa.test1 = 1;
aa.test2 = 2;
mya->SetParameters(aa);

auto data = myB->GetParameters();
```

I want to see the result of data is
`data.test1 = 1; data.test2 = 2;`
not
`data.test1 = 0; data.test2 = 0;`

Because BParameters inherit AParameters, is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Sure, many ways. The question is what the relationship is between different `A`s and `B`s. If they all share parameters, you could use `static` class members. If just some of them share parameters, how is that relationshop defined?

Comment: @super Sorry, what do you mean about  the relationship is between A and B?

I assume the code of A and B just like that, and B inherit  A.

I want to connect the data of BParameters  b in class B and AParameters a in class A

Comment: All I need is to get the result like "example". Could you try to implement your method?

Comment: What you need is to explain what you want. Let's say you create a second `B`. Shold that one also share parameters with `A` and the first `B`?

Comment: Oh, wait. There's only one instance. Misread your example a bit. So why do they have different parameter classes? Seems like you could just put a `BParameters` in `A` and be done with it?

Comment: that's because A is B's parent and A cannot see BParameters class. A and AParameters are in one package , and B and BParametes are in another. The relationship of them is that A can see Aparameters; B can see A,Aparameters and BParameters; Aparameters can can none of others; and BParamters can see AParameteres.

Comment: I want to know that can we use the advantage of inheritance to implement this question?

Comment: And why do you need the inheritance between `AParameter` and `BParameters` then? If you just remove that iheritance your current code will work.

Comment: The thing is.. what is good and bad in this kind of situation usually comes down to using a good design to start with. To just "make it work" is often a bad idea, since if you don't start with a good design it will create more problems for you in the future.

Comment: Honestly, I dont know if it is a good design. More information of my purpose are in the comments of the next answer. If you can understand my purpose, I would like to get your idea or design method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to approach it.

```
#include <memory>

class AParameters
{
public:
    AParameters();
    int test1 = 0;
    int test2 = 0;
};

class BParameters : public AParameters
{
public:
    BParameters();
    int test3 = 0;
    int test4 = 0;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() : a(std::make_unique<AParameters>()) {}
    A(std::unique_ptr<AParameters> params) : a(std::move(params)) {}
    void SetParameters(AParameters);
    AParameters GetParameters();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<AParameters> a;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A(std::make_unique<BParameters>()) {}
    void SetParameters(BParameters);
    BParameters GetParameters();
};
```

I'm not to fond of the overall design to be honest. But it's not very clear from your question what you're actually trying to achieve, so here is the "just make it work" example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try it later.
in fact, I want to design a pattern for 3D camera with three level. The first level is "camera", second level is "area scan camera" or "line scan camera", the third level under "area scan camera" are kinds of it just like "kinect" or some other different camera brand of a product;  the third level under "line scan camera" are kinds of some line scan camera brand of a product. The three level inherit two, two inherit one.
So, for example that if my program use area scan camera, most the code can be the same when I change camera pruduct.

Comment: Or if I want to write a program to do basic scanning without knowing ant kind of camera will be used. I can use the first level class to do the basic scan, and don't have to care about the kind of camera will be used. I don’t know if this kind of narration can make you understand my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: when I set basic parameters in class of level 1, I can use the pointer of level 2 to get the basic parameters. Others, when I set basic and advance parameters in calss of level 2, I can use the pointer of level 1 to get the basic parameters.